# Unwanted white space before a language command

Tags: languages

I have a problem with a command which sets the greek language for a section of text, which I defined as follows: `\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\selectlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}#1}}`.

After I did some updates, it prints an unwanted space before the text included in the new command, as you can see in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}
\setmainfont{times.ttf}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{times.ttf}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\selectlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}#1}}

\begin{document}

text \grk{καλός}

text καλός

\end{document}
```

Which gives this output:

[image]

How can I do to remove the unwanted white space?

Comment: Please update your TeX installation. If I try your example with TeXLive 2019, I get the same big space. But with an up-to-date TeXLive 2020 it is fixed.

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX and I have recently updated it, but it seems that it dependend from package polyglossia, which I updated and now it works. Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been fixed by updating the TeX distribution

Comment: Yes, I also voted to close the question